# Schema for an RBAC (Role-based Access Control System)

Tags: database-design, relational-theory

I want to implement an RBAC, Flat based.  I've decided to base my system on the [NIST standardization model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIST_RBAC_model).

Although all fine and well, I have an inclusion to that design.

Instead of a hierarchy for roles, I have a hierarchy at the permissions side: each permission will be related to a "module".

I'll explain with a diagram:

```
User U1 -> R1 & R2.
Role R1 -> P1, P2.
Permission P1, P2 -> Module M1.
```

1. A user can have multiple roles.
2. Multiple roles can be assigned to a single permission.
3. A permission can only be assigned to a single module.

What I have in my head in terms of a schema to hold this data, is as follows:

```
ac_users
     user_Id
     userRole_Ref

ac_user_roles
      role_Ref
      user_Ref

ac_roles
      role_Id
      role_Title

ac_modules
      mod_Id
      mod_Title
      modPerm_Ref

ac_permisions
      perm_Id
      perm_Title

ac_permision_roles
      pr_Id
      pr_Role
      prPerm_Ref
```

I'm worried this will cause to much overhead for this particular design.

The basic concept is that all tables will need to have a many-to-many relationship, except for `ac_permissions` which will have a many-to-one relationship with `ac_modules`.

Could anyone point out flaws with this design?

Comment: How do you define a module? Where is the "operation" equivalent in BARC?

Comment: Why not use your database's built-in users and roles?